# The only factor that is common to 200 and an integer n is 1. When $n/200$ what is the minimum number of digits to the right of the decimal point?

Tags: factoring

An ACT math problem:

> The only factor that is common to 200 and an integer $n$ is 1. When $\frac{n}{200}$ is written as a decimal number, what is the minimum number of digits to the right of the decimal point?

What are some quicker methods to get around this as opposed to trying out a bunch of assumed $n$?

Comment: Well, some playing around is useful.  Is it possible to have only $1$ digit?  What about $2$?  Can you do $3$?

Comment: Note that $n/200$ is a multiple of $1/200 = 0.005$. Can you reduce the number of digits to less than 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\dfrac 1{200} = 0.005$, we can say that $3$ decimal places are possible at maximum. If the decimal places to the right have to reduce, the ending digits must be zero and it achieved by multiplying $0.005$ with a multiple of $2$, but that violates the condition that $gcd(200,n) = 1$ as $1$ is the only common divisor for $200$ and $n$.

Hence, the minimum number of decimal places is also $3$.

Comment: Not sure if this simplifies it a bit, but I would go this way: n/200 = 0.005n. To have a zero at the third digit, n must be even, but since gcd(n,200) = 1, n must be odd and therefore it cannot be that the third digit is zero.

Comment: @RüdiJehn I intended to help him get the fact that one can use the first technique to determine the maximum places possible in the decimal representation... anyway am I too correct (even if I had to take a round trip instead of the hyperloop) ?

Comment: You cannot have four places to the right unless the fourth is zero.  As long as the GCD with $200$ is $1$ you will have exactly three.

Comment: @RossMillikan I talked about the general case...

Comment: @RossMillikan if $5n$ has $4$ digits what I said about the maximum number of decimal places to the right is true...

Comment: If the GCD is not $1$ there could be less than three places, but not more.  $\frac 1{1000}=0.001$ has three places.  No, if $5n \gt 1000$ you will get one place in front of the decimal and three after

Comment: @RossMillikan true...

Comment: @RossMillikan is the answer okay, anyway ? It's all that I wanna know

Comment: The bold statement is wrong.  As long as the GCD is $1$, there will be exactly three decimal places.  You can reduce the number if $n$ has some factors in common with $200$, but not increase it.  You should say that there is a maximum of three places, then justify that it cannot be reduced when the GCD is $1$

Comment: @RossMillikan I have edited the answer to make my long way short.. hope you like it...

Comment: @RossMillikan I think I made a small sighting mistake in the first version of the answer. The bold sentence was wrong because I counted the number of digits in $1000$ in the denominator instead of the number of $0$'s. Thanks for pointing it out (and for making me simplify things )